# Work around for apps with existing Subscription model when using commentator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using [commontator gem](https://github.com/lml/commontator) for implementing comments feature.But there is an issue since this gem also uses a subscription model and our gem also uses subscription model.
So there is a thread_id column associated with commontator's subscription table.But as it is accessing our subscription model....It gives an err `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column subscriptions.thread_id does not exist`

To the thread model which is actually giving the err and which has the association `has_many: subscriptions` ...I added the class_name as follows

```
module Commontator
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :closer, polymorphic: true, optional: true
belongs_to :commontable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :subscriptions, class_name: "Commontator::Subscription", dependent: :destroy
```

But this too still returns my subscription model:

```
pry(#<Commontator::Thread>)> subscriber.subscriptions
=> [#<Subscription:0x00007fabcc5d3340
  id: 1,
  kind: "free",
  end_date: nil,
  user_id: 2,
  channel_id: 1,
  created_at: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 11:21:15 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 11:21:15 UTC +00:00>]
```

My user.rb includes `has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy`

Commontator's subscription model vs my_subscription model

```
irb(main):017:0> Commontator::Subscription.new
=> #<Commontator::Subscription id: nil, subscriber_type: nil, subscriber_id: nil, thread_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):018:0> Subscription.new
=> #<Subscription id: nil, kind: "free", end_date: nil, user_id: nil, channel_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Is there some way I can handel this without changing the name of my Subscription model??

Answer (score 0):

@vaishnavi, [commontator](https://github.com/lml/commontator/issues) rails engine requires you to add `acts_as_commontator` to the model which should be allowed to comment.

In most of the rails application that would obviously include `User` model

Here is the [PR](https://github.com/pikender/commontator/pull/1) which has changes needed to fix the problem.

Please try with `gem 'commontator', git: "git@github.com:pikender/commontator.git", branch: "fixes/issue-135"` in your `Gemfile` and help others by testing and confirming, if it fixes the issue for you.

Hoping this fixes your problem and happy coding :)

---

Adding changes diff here for future reference, in case above PR gets deleted or lost

Change required is simple to change `subscriptions` association to `commontator_subscriptions` and change its references which are just only two (feeling lucky :) )

```
diff --git a/app/models/commontator/thread.rb b/app/models/commontator/thread.rb
index 83e51e3..b410b23 100644
--- a/app/models/commontator/thread.rb
+++ b/app/models/commontator/thread.rb
@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ module Commontator

     def subscription_for(subscriber)
       return nil if !subscriber || !subscriber.is_commontator
-      subscriber.subscriptions.where(thread_id: self.id).first
+      subscriber.commontator_subscriptions.where(thread_id: self.id).first
     end

     def subscribe(subscriber)
diff --git a/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb b/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb
index 1497ebb..2fe11a6 100644
--- a/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb
+++ b/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb
@@ -17,12 +17,12 @@ module Commontator

           has_many :comments,      as: :creator,
                                    class_name: 'Commontator::Comment'
-          has_many :subscriptions, as: :subscriber,
+          has_many :commontator_subscriptions, as: :subscriber,
                                    class_name: 'Commontator::Subscription',
                                    dependent: :destroy
         end
       end
diff --git a/spec/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator_spec.rb b/spec/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator_spec.rb
index 11a9cda..cade863 100644
--- a/spec/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator_spec.rb
+++ b/spec/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator_spec.rb
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@ module Commontator
     it 'must modify models that act_as_commontator' do
       user = DummyUser.create
       expect(user).to respond_to(:comments)
-      expect(user).to respond_to(:subscriptions)
+      expect(user).to respond_to(:commontator_subscriptions)
       expect(user).to respond_to(:commontator_config)
       expect(user.commontator_config).to be_a(CommontatorConfig)
     end
```

Comment: hii sorry, was a bit busy..actually had tried the same earlier but it didn't work..It was still pointing to my apps Subscription model..But sure can give it another try...Maybe I missed something ::(.   Will let u know soon!

Comment: @Vaishnavi we can skip changing the gem and instead patch the `lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb` and `app/models/commontator/thread.rb` in our app as per changes above.

To avoid `subscriptions` to be overridden, care might be taken with order of placing `acts_as_commonotator` before our associations definitions so that app defined gets preference over gem ones.

Let's see if we can prepare a sample app and co-ordinate over it with possible changes and issues to fix if above changes doesn't work for you